# Stream.ReadAsync not working for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Problem similar [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776448/readonlystream-readasync-not-working-for-windows-phone-8-1) one.
The app has to communicate with a camera via wlan.

On Windows 8.1 the app works fine - everything is ok.
On Windows Phone 8.1 I get after some successfully calls of ReadAsync(...) the NotSupportedException.

I open the stream in this way:

```
 public async Task<Stream> OpenHttpURLConnectionAsync(string url)
 {
   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
   var r = (WebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
   if (r != null)
   {
     try
     {
       return r.GetResponseStream();
     }
     catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
     {
       Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
       return null;
     }
   }
   throw new Exception("Cannot connect to service");
}
```

And use this stream in this function:

```
public async Task<byte[]> ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, int length)
{
  if (stream != null)
  {
    byte[] Puffer = new byte[length];
    int Position = 0;
    int BlockSize = 128;
    int Rest = length;
    while ((Position < length))
    {
      if (Rest < BlockSize)
        BlockSize = Rest;
      int ReadCount  = await s.ReadAsync(Puffer, Position, BlockSize, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
      Position += ReadCount;
      Rest -= ReadCount;
    }
    return Puffer;
  }
  return null;
}
```

In the store app the stream type is System.Net.Stream,
in the phone app the type is System.Net.ConnectStream.

I tried different blocksizes, but this won't changed the behavior: As store app everything works fine, as phone app it won't works:
The first ReadAsync reads 8 Byte and works.
The second ReadAsync reads 128 Bytes and works too.
Then, the app has to read some "massdata" (a jpeg) and after 1316 bytes the ReadAsync-call throws the NotSupportedException.

Any idea?

Greetings from Germany
Ralf

Comment: And is there a message with the exception? (Also, it would make your code easier to read if you followed .NET naming conventions, with `camelCase` for local variables.)

Comment: Well i faced the same problem as mentioned in the post referenced by you already. We changed from system.net.http to windows.web.http and it worked. So definitely some problem with system.net.http which is worth investigating . We found HTTPClient of system.net not pretty much useful when used in Windows runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @saurav: Yes, the System.net.http is the problem:

> The System.Net.Http and System.Net.Http.Headers namespace might not be available in future versions of Windows for use by Windows Store apps. Starting with Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, use Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient in the Windows.Web.Http namespace and the related Windows.Web.Http.Headers and Windows.Web.Http.Filters namespaces instead for Windows Store apps.

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn469431.aspx) for details.

It seems, that the 8.1 phone implementation of the httpclient isn't very well.

The change to windows.net.http solves my problem completly - thanks again to @saurav.

Greetings from Germany
Ralf